# Data not saving in models sequentally

Tags: django, reactjs, django-models, django-rest-framework, axios

Want to save data in sequence

I am using react as front and I am trying to save data from an array to django backend model. Suppose I have array of length 5, I am saving 5 indexes separately in Django model, but the problem is data is not saving in model in sequence.
e.g:

```
arr[0]=data1
arr[2]=data2
arr[3]=data3
```

but in model, It displays :

```
id=1
data=2,
id2=2
data=3,
id3=3
data=1,
```

I want to save in sequence, like data1, data2, data3 or data3, data2, data1 can also work, below is my code:

```
 for (let i=0; i<rowdata.length; i++){

        console.log("rows",rowdata[i]); //1,2,3,4,5,6

        payload={
            product: this.state.productid,
            row_name: rowdata[i]  // indexes data is 1,2,3,4,5,6
        };


    axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/pharmacy/create_row/',payload)
            .then(res=>{
                console.log(res)
            })
            .catch(err=>{
                console.log(err)
            })
}
```

Django Rest Response:

```
{
    "id": 43,
    "row_name": "4",
    "product": 17
},
{
    "id": 44,
    "row_name": "1",
    "product": 17
},
{
    "id": 45,
    "row_name": "5",
    "product": 17
},
{
    "id": 46,
    "row_name": "2",
    "product": 17
},
{
    "id": 47,
    "row_name": "3",
    "product": 17
},
{
    "id": 48,
    "row_name": "6",
    "product": 17
}
```

Views.py:

```
class CreateRow(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        return Response([RowSerializer(dat).data for dat in TableRow.objects.all()])

    def post(self, request):
        payload = request.data
        serializer = RowSerializer(data=payload)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

whereas it should be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 (row_name) from top to bottom, but they are not in sequence

How can I resolve it should save in like 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 or 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 both will work.

Comment: in your Django View, try to order your data by using `order_by` method. `Model.objects.all().order_by('row_name')`, then you'll have the data which have been ordered

Comment: but data can also be non-numeric. e,g row_name can aslo be entry1,entry2...

Comment: Yeah, SQL Order By will handle that for you. It will use alphabet order to ordering your data so it will be exactly what you want.